The Kernel of my Jupyter notebook is dead
I have a problem with Jupyter notebook. I installed keras because I wanted to use LSTM and when I run my code the kernel died.

I am beginner with Python.

First I uninstalled keras and restart the kernel but it did not work.
I also have tried to remove tensorflow and restart the kernel after that, but no result.

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Try restarting your kernel from the top of the notebook interface. Moreover you can check whether you have the correct python interpreter selected in VSCode. Still if it doesnt work then I would rec you to update jupyter pip install --upgrade jupyter.
LAST OPT - REINSTALL VSC

Thank you for your answer. I made update of jupyter but it did not work. So i reinstalled VSC on my Mac but unfortunately i still have the same problem...
